# A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I get the following kind of error or warning when I create a certificate. How can I fix it?

> A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain

Answer (score 0):

Select your particular device (UDID of the device you are using) when creating your provisioning profile.